# Capslock Verifier AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I can't find how I can check if the capslock is on or off.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear on what you're asking?

Comment: verify if the capslock is on or off

Comment: With what, on what operating system, through what program, uses, reasons, explain a bit.

Comment: look the title man, autohotkey

Comment: Just because it says AutoHotKey in your title doesn't mean that everyone that sees it will automatically know that you want to do this with AutoHotKey. If someone asked, they probably didn't know what you meant by AutoHotKey in your title and you should probably make both your title and your question more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [GetKeyState](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm).

```
state := GetKeyState("Capslock", "T")  ; True if CapsLock is ON, false otherwise.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
state := GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")
if state 
  MsgBox CapsLock is Enabled
else
  MsgBox CapsLock is Disabled
```

Comment: Stupid captcha.

Answer (score 1):

Use [GetKeyState](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm)

```
if GetKeyState("Capslock", "T")
      ;do something because Caps Lock is on
else
      ;Caps Lock is off
return
```